# Convert DMS coordinates to decimal degrees in R

Tags: r, coordinates, gis, r-sf, r-sp

I have the following coordinates in DMS format. I need to convert them to decimal degrees.

```
# Libraries
> library(sp)
> library(magrittr)

# Latitide & Longitude as strings
> lat <- '21d11m24.32s'
> lng <- '104d38m26.88s'
```

I tried:

```r
> lat_d <- char2dms(lat, chd='d', chm='m', chs='s') %>% as.numeric()
> lng_d <- char2dms(lng, chd='d', chm='m', chs='s') %>% as.numeric()

> print(c(lat_d, lng_d))
[1]  21.18333 104.63333
```

Although close, this result is different from the output I get from [this website](https://www.fcc.gov/media/radio/dms-decimal). According to this site, the correct output should be:

> Latitude: 21.190089
>
> Longitude: 104.6408

It seems that `sp::char2dms` and `as.numeric` are rounding the coordinates. I noticed this issue when converting a large batch of DMS coordinates using this method because the number of unique values decreases drastically after the conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right! To tell you the truth, I didn't notice this problem.
To get around this, here is a solution with the use of the package `measurements`:

**REPREX:**

```r
install.packages("measurements") 
library(measurements)

lat <- conv_unit('21 11 24.32', from = "deg_min_sec", to = "dec_deg")
long <- conv_unit('104 38 26.88' , from = "deg_min_sec", to = "dec_deg")

print(c(lat, long))
#> [1] "21.1900888888889" "104.6408"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Edit from OP

This can also be solved by adding `'N'` or `'S'` to latitude and `'E'` or `'W'` to longitude.

```r
# Add character to lat & long strings
> lat_d <- char2dms(paste0(lat,'N'), chd='d', chm='m', chs='s') %>% as.numeric()
> lng_d <- char2dms(paste0(lng,'W'), chd='d', chm='m', chs='s') %>% as.numeric()
> print(c(lat_d, lng_d))
[1]   21.19009 -104.64080
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your instructive feedback @Arturo Sbr

Comment: Thanks! I added an alternative solution to your answer. Turns out that `sp` rounds inputs if the strings are missing the last character (N, S, W or E).